# Is moving large data between Service Fabric services an antipattern?

Tags: design-patterns, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateful, service-fabric-stateless

I'm developing a web data crawler using Service Fabric.
I've devided a crawling proccess into Stateless services pipeline.
First service loads HTML. (S1)
Second one parses data from it. (S2)
Third one saves result into DB and performs additional operations. (S3)
HTML code moves from S1 to S2, than to S3 (by design, I need HTML in third service).
The problem that HTML itself is a big amount of data and I am forced to set

```
[assembly: FabricTransportServiceRemotingProvider(MaxMessageSize = 1073741824)]
```

Is this design an antipattern? Should I perform all work with HTML inside singe service?

Answer (score 3):

There is always a bandwidth + latency cost involved when dividing a single task across multiple services.  Because there is a cost, you need a good reason to do it.  You don't seem to have one, or at least you haven't mentioned one.

Making problems for no good reason is an anti-pattern.

If you *do* have a good reason for dividing this work up into services, then maybe you can justify the cost of sending all this HTML around.  It's more likely, though, that you should pick a different service decomposition that doesn't require it.

Answer (score 1):

A good design always come with good understanding of the data and the requirement. 
Is there any dependencies between S1, S2, S3,S4? If there is is there a need for them to be separate services.

Is there any dependencies between services and the HTML. Is this HTML will be changes and if it change will in cause multiple services to be updated?

There is IO cost with what you are doing? How much time you spent to transmit and how much time your process take.